# codename one video placeholder in a container

Tags: video, codenameone

I would like to resize the video to play in a specific container of the form as shown in the image below...

how can I achieve this?

[image: screenshot eample from another app]

Comment: If you need to know the original width and height of the video to calculate the new size according to the form width, this cn1lib has methods to get the video size: https://github.com/jsfan3/CN1Libs-VideoOptimizer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to size the video and how you want the screen to behave on scrolling but in general size in Codename One has two factors: Layout and Preferred Size.

Preferred size is the value any Codename One component provides to indicate its desired dimension in pixels. This isn't fixed as the value changes based on font size, device density, theme etc.

For video preferred size is very problematic as the video is usually not loaded during the layout stage (and much later too if it's streamed).

Some layouts ignore the preferred size of the child for some cases (e.g. border layout center constraint, table layout where width/height is specified etc.). Those are probably the best tools to work with for most cases.

However, the simplest approach is often just overriding `calcPreferredSize` or invoking `setPreferredSize()` on the component.